# Iteration of table rows and click the button/link within the row

Tags: java, selenium

I have this table and each row has a link to do a function. With the code that I have, it is clicking the first row and what I want to achieve is to find if item is equals to the item within the row and click the button once find the row. Here's the example:

```
    WebElement baseTable = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='materials']"));
    List<WebElement> materialsRow = baseTable.findElements(material_table_tr);
    List<WebElement> clickAction = driver.findElements(material_first_column);


    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < materialsRow.size(); i++) {
            String name = materialsRow.get(i).getText();
            Thread.sleep(500);
            if (name.contains(item)) {
                clickAction .get(i).click();
            } else
                throw new Exception("Invalid Selection");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
```

Expected: 
item=Taipei 101

find a row in which **name** is same as **item**. if find, click the button within the row.

Actual:
the code above only clicks the first row.

[Please see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jD8GI.png)

HTML:

```
<tbody>
<tr>
    <th scope="row">Burj Khalifa</th>
    <td>UAE</td>
    <td>Dubai</td>
    <td>829m</td>
    <td>2010</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><a href="#">details</a></td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
    <th scope="row">Clock Tower Hotel</th>
    <td>Saudi Arabia</td>
    <td>Mecca</td>
    <td>601m</td>
    <td>2012</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><a href="#">details</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th scope="row">Taipei 101</th>
    <td>Taiwan</td>
    <td>Taipei</td>
    <td>509m</td>
    <td>2004</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td><a href="#">details</a></td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
    <th scope="row">Financial Center</th>
    <td>China</td>
    <td>Shanghai</td>
    <td>492m</td>
    <td>2008</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td><a href="#">details</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please post the HTML of the table and properly format it. If you need help formatting, please see the formatting help when you edit your question.

Comment: There is no data `taipei 101` there is `Taipei 101`

Comment: Also you do not want to throw an exception inside the loop - think about it.

Comment: @ScaryWombat, i've edited the item= Taipei 101

Comment: So, if your first rows data does not match you will throw an exception.

Comment: @ScaryWombat if item could not be found within each row, it will throw exception.

Comment: No, if an exception is thrown the loop will be ended as the catch is outside of the `loop`

Comment: @ScaryWombat let me try to remove the exception

Comment: @ScaryWombat, it works.. Thanks :) but i dont know where to throw error when item not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your code to be

```
   boolean found = false;
   for (int i = 0; i < materialsRow.size(); i++) {
       String name = materialsRow.get(i).getText();
       Thread.sleep(500);
       if (name.contains(item)) {
           clickAction .get(i).click();
           found = true;
           break;  // do not need to look anymore
        } 
   }

   if (!found) throw new Exception ("not found");
```

Comment: Thanks for this.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use the below xpath rather the loop.

```
//table//tr[th[.='Taipei 101']]/td/a
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

here is the click line of code.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table//tr[th[.='Taipei 101']]/td/a")).click();
// generic line of code using item
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table//tr[th[.='" + item +"']]/td/a")).click();
```

If you want to check and then click, you can use the below logic.

```
    List<WebElement> items =driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table//tr[th[.='" + item +"']]/td/a"));
    if items.size()>0{
       // click on the item
       items.get(0).click();
    }else{
     // write your logic here when item not exist
    }
```